# Ul li elements exceeding DIV height

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a div with fixed height and it has Ul, li elements, so if the contents of the ul/li elements exceed the div height, it should align to the right side and not overflow outside the div. I have tried everything but not able to achieve it, below is my code:

```css
div {
  max-height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>ItemsA</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>ItemsB</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>ItemsC</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd highly suggest wrapping each `<ul>` and its associated `<h3>` into a container, so you can control the layout much better. In whatever layout you're using, it would directly affect both the `<ul>` and the `<h3>`-elements individually. By wrapping the two associated elements into separate containers, the layout properties are affecting those containers only.

One way to solve this is using `flex-wrap`. By applying `flex-direction: column`, the flex-flow will try to put the elements in a single column, and if they can't, they will wrap into a new column.

```css
/* Simple reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>ItemsA</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>ItemsB</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>ItemsC</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
    <h3>ItemsD</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want place a row of li elements. You can give the div `display: flex` feature. If the height of the lis exceeds the height of the div, you can use `overflow-y: auto`. This puts the scroll bar to parent div

```css
.parent {
  max-height: 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>
    <h3>ItemsA</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>
     <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3>ItemsB</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>
     <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3>ItemsC</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>
     <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3>ItemsD</h3>
    <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>
     <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but I dont want my li elements to be next to each other, its only if there is no space in the div it should align to side row @Otabek Sharipov

Comment: also if I have a 4th h3 and Ul/li elements it will overflow outside again as now I only have 3 h3 and ul li elements

Comment: Yes, you can use display: flex; If you have a lot of divs there is overflow-y: auto or overflow-x: auto property. When there is no space there will be scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <div>
    <h3>ItemsA</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>ItemsB</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>ItemsC</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).